# Load and Parse WPF Window XAML File

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am creating a Visual Studio Add-in that gets access to the currently opened file. The intention later to load XAML file, loop through its controls, convert each control to a different format stored in XML file.

So far, I was able to get this far. Problem is, no UIElements are being returned when I call FindVisualChildren() method.

Any idea?

```
StreamReader mysr = new StreamReader(pathToXaml);
DependencyObject rootObject = XamlReader.Load(mysr.BaseStream) as DependencyObject;

string s = "";
foreach (UIElement ui in FindVisualChildren<UIElement>(rootObject))
{
      s += ui.GetType().Name + "\n";
}


public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your xaml code? n what is yield?

Comment: It's a normal WPF Window. the problem is with VisualTreeHelper. Seems not to work when XAML is loaded dynamically. LogicalTreeHelper seems to work well.